# SwiftUI - Always left (leading) align navigationBarItems(leading: Text(""))

Tags: swiftui, navigationview

I have a **NaivgationView** that has dynamic Leading item. That is  to say, when a user taps on a button, its text gets updated. So it is not always the same.

This code has similar function as of my project.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedDay: String = "Wednesday"
    let days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(0..<days.count) {day in
                        Button(action: {
                            self.selectedDay = days[day]
                        }, label: {
                            Text(days[day])
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarItems(leading: Text($selectedDay.wrappedValue))
        }
    }
}
```

I want that the text must be left aligned always. But if a text has fewer letters than the first one, it is not on the left. For example in the code above, `Wednesday` is on the very left edge, but friday is not. There is like 16 points on its leading side. So How to left align text?

---

I have used this code also but stil has the same issue.

```
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
     Text($selectedDay.wrappedValue)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a frame to the Text and set its alignment:

```
   .navigationBarItems(leading:
                            Text(selectedDay)
                                .frame(width: 100, alignment: .leading)
    )
```

Comment: You don't need binding here, value will be updated if to use property directly as well.

Comment: Thanks. @Asperi & @ nicksarno isn't there a way to do it without using fixed size?